# Why so many freezes after upgrading to Ubuntu 21.10?

Tags: freeze, 21.10, apple

My 2009 Apple iMac had been running pretty well on Ubuntu 21.04, but after upgrading to 21.10 (via Software update) it freezes frequently, particularly when using an internet browser.

Processor: 2.66 GHz Intel Core 2 Duo. It is dedicated to Linux, not partitioned.

Here is the output of `sudo lshw`:

```
description: All In One
    product: iMac9,1 (System SKU#)
    vendor: Apple Inc.
    version: 1.0
    serial: YM922AYB0TF
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.4 dmi-2.4 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=all-in-one family=Mac sku=System SKU# uuid=142D0E89-CDCA-D145-AE66-BC80E8BFEB0F
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Mac-F2218EA9
       vendor: Apple Inc.
       physical id: 0
       serial: Base Board Serial#
       slot: Part Component
     *-cpu:0
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8135  @ 2.66GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8135  @ 2.66GHz
          slot: U2E1
          size: 1700MHz
          capacity: 2660MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 266MHz
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl cpuid aperfmperf pni dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm pti tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority vpid dtherm cpufreq
        *-cache
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 2
             slot: Unknown
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
     *-cache:0
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 1
          slot: Unknown
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-cpu:1
          description: CPU
          vendor: Intel(R) Corporation
          physical id: 3
          bus info: cpu@1
          version: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8135  @ 2.66GHz
          slot: U2E1
          size: 2236MHz
          capacity: 2660MHz
          clock: 266MHz
          capabilities: cpufreq
        *-cache
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: Unknown
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back data
             configuration: level=1
     *-cache:1
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 4
          slot: Unknown
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: asynchronous internal write-back instruction
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 6
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: IMSH2GS13A1F1C-10F
             vendor: 0x8551
             physical id: 0
             serial: 0x2A000B26
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1067 MHz (0.9 ns)
             product: IMSH2GS13A1F1C-10F
             vendor: 0x8551
             physical id: 1
             serial: 0x2A00F026
             slot: DIMM0
             size: 2GiB
             clock: 1067MHz (0.9ns)
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Apple Inc.
          physical id: e
          version: IM91.88Z.008D.B08.0904271717
          date: 04/27/09
          size: 1MiB
          capacity: 4MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect acpi ieee1394boot smartbattery netboot
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: MCP79 Host Bridge
          vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: b1
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 66MHz
        *-memory:0 UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: MCP79 Memory Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 0.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:00.1
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: MCP79 LPC Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: b2
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: ioport:2000(size=256)
        *-memory:1 UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: MCP79 Memory Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 3.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.1
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
             configuration: latency=0
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: MCP79 SMBus
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 3.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.2
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm cap_list
             configuration: driver=nForce2_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:0 ioport:2180(size=64) ioport:2140(size=64) ioport:2100(size=64)
        *-memory:2 UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: MCP79 Memory Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 3.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.3
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
             configuration: latency=0
        *-memory:3 UNCLAIMED
             description: RAM memory
             product: MCP79 Memory Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 3.4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.4
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz (15.2ns)
             configuration: latency=0
        *-processor UNCLAIMED
             description: Co-processor
             product: MCP79 Co-processor
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 3.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.5
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: memory:d3500000-d357ffff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:20 memory:d3588000-d3588fff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-27-generic ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Hub in Apple Extended USB Keyboard
                   vendor: Mitsumi Electric
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: usb@3:3
                   version: 1.22
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=hub maxpower=50mA slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: Apple Extended USB Keyboard
                      vendor: Mitsumi Electric
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@3:3.1
                      version: 1.22
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=50mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Mouse
                      product: Apple Optical USB Mouse
                      vendor: Mitsumi Electric
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@3:3.3
                      version: 1.10
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: IR Receiver
                   vendor: Apple Computer, Inc.
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@3:5
                   version: 0.16
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 4.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.1
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: debug pm ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:17 memory:d3589200-d35892ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-27-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Video
                   product: Built-in iSight
                   vendor: Apple Inc.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 2.19
                   serial: 8T95B56232CW3L00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: MCP79 OHCI USB 1.1 Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 6
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm ohci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:22 memory:d3587000-d3587fff
           *-usbhost
                product: OHCI PCI host controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-27-generic ohci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-1.10
                configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: BRCM2046 Hub
                   vendor: Apple Inc.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@4:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
                      vendor: Apple Inc.
                      physical id: 1
                      bus info: usb@4:1.1
                      version: 2.08
                      serial: 0025BC61CFEC
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 bluetooth
                      configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: MCP79 EHCI USB 2.0 Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 6.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:06.1
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: debug pm ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:22 memory:d3589100-d35891ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.13.0-27-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=5 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: MCP79 High Definition Audio
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 8
             bus info: pci@0000:00:08.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0 maxlatency=5 mingnt=2
             resources: irq:20 memory:d3580000-d3583fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: MCP79 PCI Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 9
             bus info: pci@0000:00:09.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode cap_list
             resources: memory:d3400000-d34fffff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: MCP79 Ethernet
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0a.0
             logical name: enp0s10
             version: b1
             serial: 00:25:4b:ce:f4:fc
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=forcedeth driverversion=0.64 latency=0 link=no maxlatency=20 mingnt=1 multicast=yes port=MII
             resources: irq:30 memory:d3586000-d3586fff ioport:21e0(size=8) memory:d3589000-d35890ff memory:d3589300-d358930f
        *-sata
             description: SATA controller
             product: MCP79 AHCI Controller
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0b.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: sata pm msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0 maxlatency=1 mingnt=3
             resources: irq:27 ioport:21d8(size=8) ioport:21ec(size=4) ioport:21d0(size=8) ioport:21e8(size=4) ioport:21c0(size=16) memory:d3584000-d3585fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: MCP79 PCI Express Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 memory:d3300000-d33fffff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: MCP79 PCI Express Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:1000(size=4096) memory:d2000000-d30fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: C79 [GeForce 9400]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                version: b1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:29 memory:d2000000-d2ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:1000(size=128) memory:d3000000-d301ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: MCP79 PCI Express Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 memory:d3200000-d32fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller
                vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlp4s0
                version: 01
                serial: 00:25:4b:97:a7:7e
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) ip=192.168.0.24 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:18 memory:d3200000-d3203fff
        *-pci:4
             description: PCI bridge
             product: MCP79 PCI Express Bridge
             vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: b1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm msi pciexpress normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 memory:d3100000-d31fffff
           *-firewire
                description: FireWire (IEEE 1394)
                product: FW643 [TrueFire] PCIe 1394b Controller
                vendor: LSI Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                version: 07
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress ohci bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=firewire_ohci latency=0
                resources: irq:28 memory:d3100000-d3100fff
     *-pnp00:00
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 2
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:01
          product: PnP device PNP0103
          physical id: 5
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:02
          product: PnP device PNP0c02
          physical id: 7
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=system
     *-pnp00:03
          product: PnP device PNP0b00
          physical id: 8
          capabilities: pnp
          configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 9
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: WDC WD3200AAJS-4
             vendor: Western Digital
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 4A10
             serial: WD-WCAT1A790297
             size: 298GiB (320GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0 UNCLAIMED
                description: EFI GPT partition
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                capacity: 512MiB
                capabilities: primary nofs
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: 33234c9c-1470-4715-b955-9fd95b01b070
                size: 297GiB
                capacity: 297GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover 64bit extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2021-08-08 10:19:15 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2022-01-23 08:37:22 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro mounted=2022-01-23 08:37:36 state=mounted
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: a
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD writer
             product: DVD-RW  DVRTS08
             vendor: PIONEER
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: Q81D
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
```

**Example 1**

Sample output from sudo dmesg -T after a freeze. Following a problem with the browser:

```
[Sun Jan 23 08:51:46 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1642927907.162:76): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/14295/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2888 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"
[Sun Jan 23 08:51:52 2022] audit: type=1326 audit(1642927913.522:77): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.chromium.chromium pid=2888 comm="chrome" exe="/snap/chromium/1878/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chrome" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7f7e3b14b89d code=0x50000
[Sun Jan 23 08:52:08 2022] audit: type=1400 audit(1642927929.014:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.chromium.chromium" name="/run/udev/data/+dmi:id" pid=2888 comm="ThreadPoolForeg" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[Sun Jan 23 08:53:32 2022] perf: interrupt took too long (2506 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
```

**Example 2**

A restart was needed when the system would not wake up from sleep. This message comes up again, flagged as 'Important' in the System section of the Logs application. Is it relevant?

```
perf: interrupt took too long (2522 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79250
```

**Example 3**

A restart is required, caused by a freeze when attempting to open Firefox and checking 'top' in Terminal at the same time. The list of System Logs looks like this:

[here's a screenshot of the System Logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8uQF.png)

The text of the first part of the screenshot is as follows (please let me know if more would be helpful):

```
perf: interrupt took too long (2505 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750

audit: type=1400 audit(1642935455.448:78): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" profile="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" name="/etc/PackageKit/Vendor.conf" pid=2063 comm="snap-store" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0

audit: type=1107 audit(1642935452.760:77): pid=729 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=2063 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=759 peer_label="unconfined"
 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

audit: type=1107 audit(1642935452.760:76): pid=729 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=2063 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=759 peer_label="unconfined"
 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

audit: type=1107 audit(1642935452.136:75): pid=729 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority" member="CheckAuthorization" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=2063 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=759 peer_label="unconfined"
 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

audit: type=1107 audit(1642935452.136:74): pid=729 uid=103 auid=4294967295 ses=4294967295 subj=unconfined msg='apparmor="DENIED" operation="dbus_method_call"  bus="system" path="/org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authority" interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties" member="GetAll" mask="send" name=":1.8" pid=2063 label="snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software" peer_pid=759 peer_label="unconfined"
 exe="/usr/bin/dbus-daemon" sauid=103 hostname=? addr=? terminal=?'

audit: type=1326 audit(1642935445.412:73): auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 ses=3 subj=snap.snap-store.ubuntu-software pid=2063 comm="snap-store" exe="/snap/snap-store/558/usr/bin/snap-store" sig=0 arch=c000003e syscall=314 compat=0 ip=0x7efea265c89d code=0x50000

audit: type=1400 audit(1642935437.788:72): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/14295/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2063 comm="snap-confine" capability=4  capname="fsetid"

audit: type=1400 audit(1642935437.048:71): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" profile="/snap/snapd/14295/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" pid=2063 comm="snap-confine" capability=39  capname="bpf"
```

How can I best pinpoint the problem for advice?

Comment: You have an NV 9400 chances are the problem is caused by nouveau driver. Unfortunately, it's not a very good driver and NV has dropped official support, thus the proprietary drivers no longer work on newer Ubuntu versions. I would start by checking if 20.04 was using proprietary or nouveau, if it was nouveau, then trying older kernel versions, but 1st backup everything

Comment: Thank you, @Matias. I had been using a proprietary driver: Nvidia 340. This was still supported by a PPA here: [https://launchpad.net/~kelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy]. In the upgrade to Ubuntu 21.10 this was removed, with a message that it was not needed. Thanks to your comment I have now tried re-selecting Nvidia. Will post further details as an answer if it is successful.

Answer (score 1):

Nouveau is the built-in driver which was performing poorly. Switch back to Nvidia 340 driver (it had been overidden during the upgrade to ubuntu 21.10).

Follow this link for nvidia 340 PPA:
[https://launchpad.net/~kelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy](https://launchpad.net/%7Ekelebek333/+archive/ubuntu/nvidia-legacy)

Install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt-get update
```

See this post for more info:
[Unable to use proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver after upgrading from Lubuntu 20.10 to 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335837/unable-to-use-proprietary-nvidia-graphics-driver-after-upgrading-from-lubuntu-20)

Please comment with any clarification about these steps, as I am not 100% clear on them, though the results are good.