# Ubuntu 22.10 and nvidia drivers not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I cannot install any of the nvidia driver for kernel 5.19, or 6.0.5 in ubuntu 22.10. I also tried downgrading my kernel, but I could not install the matching headers for kernel 5.15. I dont really know what else to do, or where else to ask for help. I created a forum post here (https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cannot-get-nvidia-driver-520-515-515-open-or-510-working-in-ubuntu-22-10/231860) with some details of my system, and what I tried. Havent really gotten any responses. Is anyone able to help me get nvidia driver running in my installation of ubuntu?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is in this forum: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cannot-get-nvidia-driver-520-515-515-open-or-510-working-in-ubuntu-22-10/231860. I did many steps to make it work, but I summarize the final steps at the bottom.

Comment: An answer in this forum should not require the user to go to another forum to get the answer. At least summarize the information here and refer to the other forum for support.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the solution in https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cannot-get-nvidia-driver-520-515-515-open-or-510-working-in-ubuntu-22-10/231860

Unfortunately I get another error.  It seems that the nvidia-520 driver is not signed and won't work with secure boot.
`sudo modprobe nvidia`
gives:
`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service`

Extra detail is that I get an empty error-popup if I try to install the 520 driver with the 'additional drivers' dialog.  So I did instead:  `sudo apt install nvidia-driver-520 nvidia-dkms-520`

But, as said, I have not yet got it working.

EDIT: I got it working now, based on this: https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/dkms-package-support-extra-drivers-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-22-10-install-media/31655

I did: `sudo kmodsign sha512 /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.priv /var/lib/shim-signed/mok/MOK.der /lib/modules/5.19.0-23-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko`  and the other modules.
And then `modprobe nvidia` did work!!

Comment: That makes sense that it didnt work with secure boot, as I have that disabled!

Comment: Didn't work in my case

Answer (score 2):

There is an [update to dkms that fixes this issue](https://github.com/linux-surface/linux-surface/issues/906) that has just been released. However, updating this package only fixes signing kernel modules for subsequently installed packages. i.e. your existing installed nvidia driver won't be updated. I fixed this by installing a different driver but you could reinstall your current one:

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-515
```

OR

```
sudo apt reinstall nvidia-driver-515
```

Note that nvidia-driver-520 doesn't seem to be available for 22.10 at the moment!

Then test to see if your driver loads

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

If so, you're good to go. **Reboot your computer** and you should have the nvidia driver working again.

If `modprobe` fails, it may be because you have Secure Boot enabled in BIOS setup. Reboot, disable, and try again.

Comment: modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service

Comment: Ensure that "Secure boot" in BIOS is dissabled.

Comment: Oh, did not know there was such a DKMS issue. Life saver! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When running `sudo modprobe nvidia` I also got

```
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'nvidia': Key was rejected by service
```

I have a NVIDIA GK208B GeForce GT 730 on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. It stopped working properly, probably after some upgrade.

`sudo apt reinstall nvidia-driver-470` didn't help, but

```
sudo apt reinstall nvidia-dkms-470
```

did. Explanation probably is, that with the last package / kernel upgrade the MOK signing got screwed up, so secure boot prevented the driver of my graphics card from being loaded, so the 2nd monitor stopped working.

Running the above started the signing process again. During the installation I was asked to set a password for the Machine Owner Key (MOK) which I had to reenter when booting again. Only challenge then was entering the password with US keyboard layout instead of German :D

After that it worked again.

Comment: Had same problem with kernel 6.2.0-25: Boot process stopped with the two mount lines (text mode). Unfortunately I have not idea how to open a terminal input at this state, so I brutally pressed the reset button.

Previous kernel -24 booted. Installing -26 some days later did not repair the system, but a genius had told me to press Alt-PrtSc-reisub to initiate a clean reboot, and afterwards, running kenel -24, I found the dmesg log containing the nvidia error code mentioned above. Your reinstall command then seemd to repair the system -- and remove kernel -25 for whatever reason.

Answer (score -1):

have you try this solution?

it's work fine with my old Powerbook 17 with elementary os 6.1

[Unable to use proprietary NVIDIA graphics driver after upgrading from Lubuntu 20.10 to 21.04 (20.04 LTS to 22.04 LTS)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335837/unable-to-use-proprietary-nvidia-graphics-driver-after-upgrading-from-lubuntu-20)

...
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/nvidia-legacy
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xorg-modulepath-fix

davide

Comment: Hi Davide, I am able to select the nvidia drivers after updating my kernel, but my pc wont boot with them still after the installation says its done.

Comment: It works with ubuntus until 22.04. Not working with ubuntu 22.10 :(